How to Trigger TextToolbar's showMenu on Focus in Jetpack Compose?
I am working with a BasicTextField in Jetpack Compose and trying to show the TextToolbar (with actions like Copy, Paste, Cut) automatically when the BasicTextField gains focus. The TextToolbar currently works fine when I trigger it manually through a press event, but it hides immediately when I attempt to trigger it on focus.
Toolbar when text is selected i want to display like this

Here is the code I am using:
fun InputEditTextWithSelection(
       value: TextFieldValue,
       modifier: Modifier,
       onValueChange: (TextFieldValue) -> Unit,
       contentTextStyle: TextStyle,
       cursorColor: Color = Color.Black,
       ) {
       val textToolbar = LocalTextToolbar.current
       val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val isFocused by interactionSource.collectIsFocusedAsState()

 
    LaunchedEffect(isFocused) {
        if (isFocused) {
            textToolbar.showMenu(
                rect = Rect(0f, 0f, 200f, 50f),
                onCopyRequested = {
                    println("Copy requested: ${value.text}")
                },
                onPasteRequested = {
                    println("Paste requested")
                },
                onCutRequested = {
                    println("Cut requested: ${value.text}")
                },
                onSelectAllRequested = {
                    println("Select All requested")
                }
            )
        } else {
            textToolbar.hide()
        }
    }

    BasicTextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = onValueChange,
        modifier = modifier
            .focusable(interactionSource = interactionSource)
            .onFocusChanged { focusState ->
                if (focusState.isFocused) {
                    onValueChange(value.copy(selection = TextRange(0, value.text.length)))
                }
            },
        textStyle = contentTextStyle,
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        cursorBrush = SolidColor(cursorColor),
    )
}

Problem:
The TextToolbar shows briefly but hides immediately after the focus event. I suspect this is related to the recomposition triggered by state changes or how the showMenu API is implemented.
Questions:

Is there a way to keep the TextToolbar open when triggered by focus without it being hidden immediately?
Is TextToolbar designed to work only with user press gestures (like long press), or is there a workaround for triggering it on focus events?

